# Convert string a to b using a dictionary of words

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph

You have a dictionary of words and two strings `a` and `b`.

How can one convert a to b by changing only one character at a time and making sure that all the intermediate words are in the dictionary?

Example:

```
dictionary: {"cat", "bat", "hat", "bad", "had"}
a = "bat"
b = "had"
```

solution:

`"bat" -> "bad" -> "had"`

EDIT: The solutions given below propose building a graph from the dictionary words such that every word will have an edge to all other words differing by just one character.
This may be somewhat difficult if the dictionary is too big (let us say we are not talking about english language words only).

Also, even if this is acceptable, what is the best algorithm to create such a graph? Finding edges from a word to all other words would be O(n) where n is dictionary size. And total graph construction would be O(n2)? Any better algorithm?

This is not homework problem but an interview question.

Comment: If the graph is too big to build in memory, consider using a database with one row for each edge.

Answer (score 2):

You can think of this as a graph search problem.  Each word is a node in the graph, and there is an edge between two words if they differ by exactly one letter.  Running a [BFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) over this graph will then find the shortest path between your start word and the destination word (if it's possible to turn one word into the other) and will report that there is no way to do this otherwise.

Comment: But if the dictionary is too big so much that it would be rather difficult to construct this graph, then how do you approach this problem?
Also, how do you construct the above graph from the dictionary? What data-structure would you use? and what algorithm to use for populating this graph?

Comment: If the dictionary is quite large, you would benefit from using A* (A star search) instead of BFS. Also, with a very large dictionary, you may not want to pre-build the graph (of course, here we are talking about a dictionary containing more than just the "roughly 1 million English words" http://www.slate.com/articles/life/the_good_word/2006/04/word_count.html). With so many nodes in the graph, you may need to determine the legal edges of the graph on the fly (which will take more processing). When you arrive at the node "hat" you start checking "aat","bat",...,"hbt",to find edges.

Comment: Perhaps you could memo-ize the edges calculated while exploring so you don't need to recalculate them each time you get back to a word.  Also, you will need to avoid going back to a node you already visited, so keep track of visited nodes.

Comment: You can always lazily build the graph as necessary.  Given the starting node, you can compute all possible strings that are one hop away from the starting word, then check each one to see if it's a valid word by seeing whether it's in the dictionary.

Comment: Even with these optimizations, order of graph construction would be O(n2) which may become too costly.

Comment: Also, finding if two strings differ by just one character is O(m).
So, overall cost of building this graph would be O(m.n2) where m is word-length and n is dictionary-size

Answer (score 0):

Simply do a BFS over the graph whose nodes are the words and there is an edge between two nodes iff the words on the nodes differ by one letter. In this way, you could provide a solution by starting BFS from the start word given. If you reach the destination node, then it's possible, otherwise not.

You could also provide the steps taken and *note that you would be providing the least number of steps to derive the required as a bonus.*

P.S.: It's a coincidence that this question was asked to me too in an interview and I coded this solution!

Comment: But if the dictionary is too big so much that it would be rather difficult to construct this graph, then how do you approach this problem?

Comment: @user2250246 If the dictionary is too big then you could make use of hashmap. Suppose, you have the dictionary stored in a file. Store the hashmap of dictionary in a separate file and then recurse starting from the word `a`. Keep marking the words in the hashmap which you have visited as visited and finally you would reach the desired word.

Comment: @user2250246 If you have any problem understanding the above, then I could explain it in my answer.

Comment: A sample execution on the sample-set given in the problem would be great.
Thanks for your effort!

Answer (score 0):

> How can one convert a to b by changing only one character at a time
>   and making sure that all the intermediate words are in the dictionary?

This is straight `O(nm)`

where `n` is number of words in the dictionary
and `m` is number of characters in the input word

The algorithm is simple, if the word from the dictionary mismatch the input by 1-character, consider it a solution:

```
FOR EACH WORD W IN DICTIONARY DO

    IF SIZE(W) = SIZE(INPUT) THEN

        MIS = 0

        FOR i: 1..SIZE(INPUT) IF W[i] != INPUT[i] THEN MIS = MIS + 1

        IF MIS = 1 THEN SOLUTION.ADD(W)

    END-IF

END-FOR
```

Answer (score 0):

Pre-build and re-use a travel map.
For example, build a scity[][] with valid word distance, that can be re-used.

Just a quick-exercise for job hunting, might be simplified.

```
#define SLEN 10
char* dict[SLEN]={
"bat",
"hat",
"bad",
"had",
"mad",
"tad",
"het",
"hep",
"hady",
"bap"};

int minD=0xfffff;
int edst(char *a, char *b)
{
 char *ip=a,*op=b;
 int d=0;
 while((*ip)&&(*op))
  if(*ip++!=*op++) 
  {
   if(d) return 0;
   d++;
  }
 if((*op)||(*ip)) d++;
 return d;
}
int strlen(char *a)
{
 char *ip=a;
 int i=0;
 while(*ip++)
  i++;
 return i;
}
int valid(char *dict[], int a, int b)
{
 if((a==b)||(strlen(dict[a])!=strlen(dict[b]))||(edst(dict[a],dict[b])!=1)) return 0;
 return 1;
}

void sroute(int scity[SLEN][SLEN], char* dict[], int a[], int end, int pos)
{
 int i,j,d=0;
 if(a[pos]==end)
 {
  for(i=pos;i<(SLEN-1);i++)
  {
   printf("%s ",dict[a[i]]);
   d+=scity[a[i]][a[i+1]];
  }
  printf(" %s=%d\n",dict[a[SLEN-1]],d);
  if(d<minD) minD=d;
  return;
 }

 for(i=pos-2;i>=0;i--)
 {
  int b[SLEN];
  for(j=0;j<SLEN;j++) b[j]=a[j];
  b[pos-1]=a[i];
  b[i]=a[pos-1];
  if(scity[b[pos-1]][b[pos]]==1)
    sroute(scity,dict,b,end,pos-1);
 }
 if(scity[a[pos-1]][a[pos]]==1) sroute(scity,dict,a,end,pos-1);
}

void initS(int scity[SLEN][SLEN], char* dict[], int a, int b)
{
 int i,j;
 int c[SLEN];
 for(i=0;i<SLEN;i++)
  for(j=0;j<SLEN;j++)
   scity[i][j]=valid(dict,i,j);
 for(i=0;i<SLEN;i++) c[i]=i;
 c[SLEN-1]=b;
 c[b]=SLEN-1;

 sroute(scity, dict, c, a, SLEN-1);
 printf("min=%d\n",minD);
}
```